# How can you compile entity bean in EJB 2.0?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

In my study I faced EJB 2.0 and I don't understand how the bean class can be compiled. It implements interface EJBLocalHome with methods like findByPrimaryKey() and create(). In XML descriptor we have mapping of methods to some other methods. But how we can compile this code if we don't implement this methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you don't compile it. At deploy time, it's the application container the one in charge of creating all the necessary proxy classes that actually *do* implement the EJB interfaces, and those classes delegate their job to the bean classes you wrote.

Comment: But I used to compile project to .war file and deploy it to app server. So, in previous version we could just place the code?

Comment: You _do_ have to compile the bean class and the EJB interfaces and pack them in a .war (or .ear). What you don't have to do, is creating and compiling the actual class that implements the interfaces, that's generated automatically for you at deploy time

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand. We don't write "implements EJBLocalHome", right? It's done for us under the hood?

Comment: That's right! that's how it works in EJB2. On the other hand, in EJB3 the bean class _must_ explicitly implement the Local and Remote interfaces, but anyway the container automatically generates proxy classes under the hood.